# Установка windows 10 после линукс

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, dual-boot

Был установлен убунту. Удалил его с жёсткого диска, предварительно сделав загрузочную виндовс. Теперь при выборе флешки с виндовс появляется grub. как быть? Из ресурсов есть убунту 12.04 на флешки.

[image: при загрузке с флешки виндовс]

Comment: скорее всего Вы сделали кривую загрузочную флешку для видны. Видимо нужно загружать убунту и искать "правильную" винду для флешки. https://www.microsoft.com/uk-ua/software-download/windows10

Comment: Советую устанавливать Windows рядом с Ubuntu.

Comment: `bootrec /fixboot && bootrec /fixmbr` из под ERD делал?

Comment: С горем пополам поставил виндовс. Теперь каждый раз через Бут меню надо жёсткий выбирать. А флешка с установкой не выбирается